# Extrair tudo usando Libarchive

Tags: python

Como faço para extrair todo o conteúdo de um arquivo compactado para o diretório atual?
P.S.: O arquivo tem pastas e arquivos.

```
import libarchive    
def unpack(file):
        #?
```

Comment: qual o formato do arquivo? o que tu tentou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar PyLZMA:

```
import pylzma
i = open(compressed_file, 'rb')
o = open(decompressed_file, 'wb')
s = pylzma.decompressobj()
while True:
    tmp = i.read(1)
    if not tmp: break
    o.write(s.decompress(tmp))
o.close()
i.close()
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma